# Bootstrap datetimepicker enter key to fill initial date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Bootstrap datetimepicker as seen here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Specifically upon first showing, the enter key should hide the widget and place the current date into the input field. Here's some stuff I tried:

There's a dp.hide event which doesn't inject clues into the callback. So, you don't know how it got triggered.

```
$("#datePicker").on("dp.hide", function(e) {
    // e.notSquat
});
```

It's just not clear which DOM element of the datetimepicker is actually receiving an enter key internally. It's definitely not the input element:

```
// handler never gets called. css selector is correct
$("#datePicker input").keypress(function(e) {
   console.log(e.which);
});
```

I braved it, somewhat, by jumping into the code of datetimepicker.js itself:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

There are clues, for example, line 2588, but my god there must be an easier way:

```
// line 2588
enter: function () {
        this.hide();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, in case anyone finds this helpful. I overwrote the keyBinds.enter property when initializing the plugin.

```
$("#datePicker").datetimepicker({
    keyBinds: {
        enter: function(){
            if(this.date() === null) {
                this.date(moment());    // moment() is similar to new Date()
            }
            this.hide();
        }
    },
    useCurrent: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem using another library - [uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) v1.8.0..

After a short investigation, I have found the reason why the enter key didn't work for me was the `forceParse` option set to `false` (**not stated in the Docs**).

Code taken from Datepicker.prototype.keydown:

```
switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 13: // enter
    if (!this.o.forceParse)
      break;
}
```

See [issue #2381](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/2381)